# Negative Utilization Numbers from SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, cpu-usage, dmv

While running performance tests in our staging environment, I occasionally will run the following query:

```
declare @ts_now bigint 
select @ts_now = ms_ticks from sys.dm_os_sys_info 

select  dateadd (ms, (y.[timestamp] -@ts_now),
GETDATE()) as EventTime,
SQLProcessUtilization, 
SystemIdle, 
100 - SystemIdle - SQLProcessUtilization as OtherProcessUtilization 
from 
    ( select record.value('(./Record/@id)[1]', 'int') as record_id, 
    record.value('(./Record/SchedulerMonitorEvent/SystemHealth/SystemIdle)[1]', 'int') as SystemIdle, 
    record.value('(./Record/SchedulerMonitorEvent/SystemHealth/ProcessUtilization)[1]', 'int') as SQLProcessUtilization, 
    timestamp 
    from 
        ( select timestamp, 
        convert(xml, record) as record 
        from sys.dm_os_ring_buffers 
        where ring_buffer_type = N'RING_BUFFER_SCHEDULER_MONITOR'
        and record like '%<SystemHealth>%') as x 
    ) as y
```

This Returns

[image: Utilization Pic]

Can anyone explain how I get a negative number for utilization?  I found this while trying to figure out a CPU utilization issue from a PSS Diag where the SQL Server CPU Utilization was larger than the System CPU utilization.

I have yet to figure out either issue but I have to assume they are related.